# Trying to post a comment appends it to the question's URL and... fails

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

Trying to post a comment [to a recently-closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198050/what-are-the-best-cities-in-asia-to-pursue-a-career-as-a-software-developer-engin) on Stack Overflow.

Instead, when i hit the "Add Comment" button, SO loads this url:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198050/what-are-the-best-cities-in-asia-to-pursue-a-career-as-a-software-developer-engin?comment=Should+have+been+closed+as+%22Too+localized%22...+or+even+%22Subjective+%26+Argumentative%22...+but+oh+well.+**%40Wing**+-+please+see%3A+http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8401%2Fwhere-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

...and no comment is posted. Note that the comment text appears in the querystring...

Comment: Weird.  It doesn't even validate that the comment is long enough or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to comment on closed posts? :)

Last night's push removed the awesome [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin.  We love it, but don't need all its functionality on this site.

We still want some client validation, so there's some very minimalistic code that's added when the question/answer editor is available on the page - **closed posts don't have the editor**!

Fixing (and I'm sorry!); will be in tonight's code push.

Answer (score 4):

That *just* happened to me while trying to comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200255/what-is-your-favorite-unicode-character-closed. I commented on a non-closed question about 15 minutes ago, so I see no obvious reason for the failure.

**Edit:** I tried several other questions, some closed, some not. Commenting worked on every open question and failed on every closed question. This is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed this behavior right now.

Is the "comment library" already fixed? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this too, except that the question I tried to comment on, someone else managed to comment after it was closed (after my attempt had failed).  I assumed that commenting on closed questions was now something only higher-rep people could do.  I guess I was wrong.

I can't find the question I first experienced it on, probably has been deleted.  It was that "Are you the owner of `<`some name vaguely related to stack or overflow`>`?" question.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed again... definitely a glitch in the matrix...

Answer (score 0):

I found that this happened when I tried to include a second jQuery library into the page with Greasemonkey. (Then I realized I could use the current one).